# How to store an MP3 file in a a database?

Tags: sql, database, mp3, media

Being new to storing data types in a database, I brought myself upon a problem whereas I need to store a media file inside some sort of database. 
I currently utilize MySQL. 
Since SO is a community which includes but is not limited to professional programmers, and one of the most high quality question and answer sites(as it pertains to programming), this question may have a fairly simple answer.

That being said, Someone explain to me how to store an abundance of media files inside an SQL database.

Please & Thank you to the stackoverflow.com community.

Comment: Why do you need to store media in a database? Doing so isn't unheard of, but it's unusual and a bit messy. Why not just use the file system?

Comment: Media types as in MP3. I need them in a database. Can MySQL handle this? I'm reading the MySQL website; and researching data types.

Comment: @Daniel: and of course the file system *is* a kind of database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To store the actual mp3 you need to store it as a blob.  A common alternative is to just store a file path.  I personally prefer the second approach if possible as they are a lot easier to work with when it comes to refactoring/deploying/testing